# How to correctly query all values of a json field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a field casted to jsonb named `industry` like this:

```
"{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'}"
"{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}"
```

I want to query all `value` values of this field

```
select  industry::json->>'value' from table
```

but the quey results in empty values

My expect results was:

```
trunk
motor
```

Comment: Your code works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xwvHhuVZt3U133ajKi9R4k/0. The only difference is in the data you have: you should use single quotes to enclose the json value, and double quotes to enclose keys (and values if the value type is a string).

Comment: @lemon Thanks.  I'll try to do this replaces in pandas as i'm loading the values using pandas.

Comment: It looks like your jsonb values are strings with json-like (but single-quoted) content, instead of actual objects. Can you make a [mcve] (including table definition and sample data), please?

Comment: yes.  It is single quoted.  I replaced the single quotes with double quotes in pandas before load the values to postgresql but then it goes with triple quotes. Getting crazy here!

Comment: Please show that code. It sounds like you still have escaped quotes in a string, not an object.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-json/), query should be `select industry->’value’ as industry from table`

Comment: I get empty results as well

Comment: Try using ```industry ->> 'value'``` and make sure you have data in your table. I am on phone so can't do much.